# Generating Random Numbers as primary key In PHP / Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, random

What is the best way to generate alphanumeric random number to 8 digit in php which is case sensitive?
I want to use this unique number to be stored in mysql data base and make it a primary key.

Comment: If it doesnt have to be alphanumeric limited to 8 digits, you could simply use an Auto-Incrementing Primary Key.

Comment: 1) There is no reason to do this. 2) No one should help you because you accept NO answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to generate a random key within PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637278/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-a-random-key-within-php)

Comment: This answer may be helpful too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307486/short-unique-id-in-php/307773#307773

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never use a random key as primary key. Primary keys need to be unique in most cases and random numbers are not.

E.g.

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
```

is also a valid output of a 8 digit random number generator.

You should use auto-increment fields or generators instead to make sure that your primary key is really unique.

If you want to have a identifier which is likely to be unique and some sort of random try to use mysql facilities like: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid

A caveat might be to reiterate inserts multiple times.

Comment: First, why never? Second, are there not random generators that yield unique output?

Comment: The design of a random number generator prevents the output of being unique.

Comment: Yes, but we can wrap it inside another generator that cuts non-unique output. Or try it anyway against the database until it is not already there (and thus accepted as primary key input). The OP's wording is not perfect but a unique random key is not unheard of.

Comment: @ypercube : it might be that the op meant this so i edited my post to add some more information regarding uuids.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could trim a hash (md5() or sha1() etc.) of a field in the item to 8 characters- although you might end up with a collision.

Why not make the primary key field AUTOINCREMENT? Why does it need to be 8 alphanumeric characters?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use the [`uniqid`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) function.

But make sure you really want to do that. An `AUTOINCREMENT` column might be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not random, but if you don't want your IDs to be sequential then perhaps you could encrypt them in some way. See the following question on the same topic: [Simple integer encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769539/simple-integer-encryption)