# Encryption integer data into database

Tags: java, database, hibernate

Hi my case is i have to encrypt integer data(mob no) and Date (DOB) into database. i'm using hibernate for database connection. i don't want to convert my existing column datatype into varchar because it will impact my whole application. is this possible to encrypt data without changing datatype.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically you could use an encryption algorithm which results in the same data type. For example, for integers this answer could be of help:

[Simple integer encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769539/simple-integer-encryption)

Whether your should do this is a whole different question. It is trivially easy to decrypt the data for as for example a date of birth has a relatively fixed format and all output varieties are easily compiled into a dictionary.